# Spring Boot: XLIFF files for translations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to manage translations in Spring Boot with XLIFF files.  In my research, property files are always used for the translations.

Do you know packages with which I can use XLIFF files for translations that can also be integrated well into Spring Boot?

Comment: Here is an package: https://github.com/alaugks/spring-messagesource-xliff